# Legal syntax for parameterized interface

Tags: system-verilog

I have a interface definition for a parameterized interface as follows :

```
interface A#(parameter adr=64,parameter data=128,parameter enable=1)(input clk, input rst);
endinterface
```

Now, can i declare something like ? Is this legal ?

```
A#(,,0) A0(clk,rst);
```

I did not find any such examples in the 1800-2012 SV LRM, so I was wondering about the legality of this syntax before I contact the EDA vendor. One such major tool vendor works perfectly fine but another major vendor complains about this - The error specifically being 
**near ",": syntax error, unexpected ','.**

Comment: The statement you show is definitely illegal. Did you mean to ask if `A#(,,0) inst();` was legal

Comment: Yup, sorry about that. I meant to emphasise on the consecutive (,,). I edited my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot skip over parameter overrides in an ordered list. It's illegal syntax according to the BNF:

```
list_of_parameter_assignments ::=
    ordered_parameter_assignment { , ordered_parameter_assignment }
  | named_parameter_assignment { , named_parameter_assignment }
ordered_parameter_assignment ::= param_expression
```

Contrast this with an ordered list of port connections:

```
list_of_port_connections29 ::=
    ordered_port_connection { , ordered_port_connection }
  | named_port_connection { , named_port_connection }
ordered_port_connection ::= { attribute_instance } [ expression ]
```

The param_expression in not optional in a parameter list, but an expression is optional in a port connection list.

Comment: Thanks Dave ! Could you please shed more light on BNF ? This is the first time I am hearing it.

Comment: Annex A of the LRM defines the accepted syntax in [Backus Naur form](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/bnf.html). If it can't be repressed in the BNF, it is not legal. However the converse is not true; not all accepted syntax is legal.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether it's legal. Two simulators rejected it and one didn't (probably the same one as you). But you could

i) rearrange the order of the parameters:

```
interface A#(parameter enable=1, parameter adr=64,parameter data=128)(input clk, input rst);
endinterface

A #(0) a (.clk, .rst);
```

ii) use *named mapping*:

```
A #(.enable(0)) a (.clk, .rst);
```

Comment: Named mapping is definitely the way to go: ordered mapping is a mistake waiting to happen

Comment: @nguthrie That's certainly true for IO and certainly better for parameters. Why wouldn't you? No project was ever late because the typing took too long.

Comment: Maybe some people have to pay by the character? Or they are competing in [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @nguthrie Named is probably the way to go, but when you are working on legacy code with thousands of declarations and different placement of ',' and projects change EDA tools, I am more interested in knowing why something used to work and now it doesn't, rather than do a sed and replace with named mapping (duh !). Maybe 'some people' aren't really satisfied unless they know the reason why as opposed to hearing so called witty comments on the internet.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewTaylor Obviously If I were to code from scratch I would stick to named mapping. I am just curious why something used to work and now it doesn't, so I was wondering if one EDA tool follows the LRM more strictly than the other.

Comment: That is certainly true